# SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser returns misleading value

Tags: security, sharepoint

I'm trying to find out current user name for my sharepoint application. There are more that one way how to do this. However the sharepoint way returns misleading value.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name // returns MY_COMPUTER\\my_user

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name // returns MY_COMPUTER\\my_user

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"] // returns MY_COMPUTER\\my_user

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName // returns SHAREPOINT\\system
```

What is the cause of this behavior? Will I encounter problems if I'll use non-sharepoint way?

Comment: This might be a setup issue as a cursory search of the internet seems to show that it returns correctly and not the SHAREPOINT\System you're seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected if the user is the application pool account running the current web application.
BTW, it's supposed to be the same name as displayed in the welcome control (upper left control)

Answer (score 6):

Are you browsing as the admin account that you used to install the system? SharePoint will "helpfully" rename that SHAREPOINT\System. Use a different account and all of the methods will return the same value.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because you are probably getting the current user from an elevated SPWeb inside a RunWithElevatedPrivileges code. You can use the snippet below to get the real user

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(siteColl.ID))
   {
       using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(site.ID))
       {
            string currUser = site.CurrentUser; //not the ElevatedSite.CurrentUser
       }
   }
});
```

This will show the real user name instead of the SHAREPOINT\System user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have include this code under SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriviliges. Check it out once. I am not sure though

Answer (score 0):

The other way SPWeb.CurrentUser could return SHAREPOINT\system is if the web is elevated, though I'm not sure why SPContext.Current would be elevated. On what kind of page are you seeing this behavior?